# " URL not found 404 error" after the 3rd page during Magento installation

Tags: magento

I have been trying to install Magento 1.6 latest version and sample data magento sample-data- 1.1.2 but all in vain.I cannot get past the 3rd page,where database,username,URL etc information is added.When I click the continue button,I get 404 error “URL not found“ .After google search I found out that some guys reported similar problems that lead to some php files accessing the Mysql server.Those files seemed to have a syntax error of some kind.My problem is of similar nature but leads to a diffrent php file having an 'an access voilation'error.The url  points to the report directory inside magento/var.
This is my report file in Public_html/magento/var/report

```
a:5:{i:0;s:223:"Error in file: "/home/archy/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/sql/directory_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.8.2-0.8.3.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'AX' for key 'PRIMARY'";i:1;s:1022:"#0 /home/archy/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
```

I don’t understand how to solve the problem.Has anyone experienced similar problems.

### New Addition..

I am really struggling with Magento!! I tried to install magento on my desktop(local server) after a failed attempt on my laptop(above).But I get I "Object not found error 404" after clicking the continue button in the configuration section of my installation.I have double checked my permissions on media, var,app directories.They are all 777.Sample date was installed before starting installation.The only option that I commented out in .htaccess was the the ExpireDefault which was causing "Internal Server Error"before being removed.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    Mage_Core_Exception: Can't retrieve entity config: sales/quote_shipping_rate in /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php on line 563

Call Stack:
    0.0296     644264   1. {main}() /home/sam/public_html/magento/index.php:0
    0.1808    1129872   2. Mage::run() /home/sam/public_html/magento/index.php:80
    0.3326    2771544   3. Mage_Core_Model_App->run() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php:640
    1.0335    4165088   4. Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:338
    5.2513    4490984   5. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:412
    7.1161    9860936   6. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php:235
    7.1163    9861520   7. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php:320
    7.1163    9861600   8. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php:437
    7.1792    9917352   9. include('/home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.16-0.9.17.php') /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php:624
    7.1810    9918112  10. Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup->addAttribute() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/sql/sales_setup/mysql4-upgrade-0.9.16-0.9.17.php:32
    7.1810    9918112  11. Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup->_flatTableExist() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Setup.php:101
   12.4649    9964680  12. Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->getTable() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Setup.php:87
   12.4649    9964680  13. Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php:184
   12.5666   10576032  14. Mage::throwException() /home/sam/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php:272

)
```

I couldn't find out what could have caused the problem.Help needed. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below script if your server or local meets the requirement to install magento

```
function extension_check($extensions) {
    $fail = '';

    if(version_compare(phpversion(), '5.2.0', '<')) {
        $fail .= '<li>PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)</li>';
    }

    if(!ini_get('safe_mode')) {
        if(preg_match('/[0-9].[0-9]+.[0-9]+/', shell_exec('mysql -V'), $version)) {
            if(version_compare($version[0], '4.1.20', '<')) {
                $fail .= '<li>MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)</li>';
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($extensions as $extension) {
        if(!extension_loaded($extension)) {
            $fail .= '<li>'.$extension.'</li>';
        }
    }

    if($fail) {
        echo '<p>Your server does not meet the requirements for Magento.';
        echo 'The following requirements failed:</p>';
        echo '<ul>'.$fail.'</ul>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Congratulations! Your server meets the requirements for Magento.</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

STEP 2 : CHeck Max Execution time 
Step 3: Install the Magento again with the version 1.6.0.0 as there were some problem at the first release  or try with latest version 1.6.2.0
Let me know if it works or not